# how to check if certain string are present in php code using php

Tags: php

some hackers just hacked into mysite and added  to some code to my poor site.

Now I want to search some certain sign they used in their code in all my php files.

currently i have the code below which will read through the php file **(scheck.php)** and display the php code.

What I want is to check all the php files for all the strings in the code. if any the string is found in the code print (eg `$string1` found) else nothing found. I already have a malware scanner install after the incident but I want to do it myself on my site. thanks

here is the code

```
 <?php



        $string1 = "eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode(";
        $string2 = "eval(base64_decode(";
        $string3 = "eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(";
        $string4 = "cmd.exe /c";
        $string5 = "find . -type f -perm -02000 -ls";
        $string6 = "ls -la";
        $string7 = '$GLOBALS[';
        $string8 = 'eval(';



// read file line by line until end
$myfile = fopen("scheck.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  echo $content = fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
}
fclose($myfile);


?>
```

**scheck.php** sample

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['aonou50'] = $r42[67].$r42[19].$r42[7].$r42[90]; 
$str = 'You cannot hack me again';

eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: Have you fixed the vulnerability that allowed you to be hacked in the first place?  If not, it's just going to happen again.

Comment: Also, if you already have this code, then what exactly is your question?  What is the result of running this code and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: yes my hosting company just fix it. I think they get access by passing php file in my page url. Getimagesize that I used to sanitize file upload was broken so they uploaded some embeded php files as image. am using fileinfo now and ensure that all data coming from url are well validated on server side

Comment: I  want check the presence of any of the string variable 1 to 8 in scheck.php code. if any is found to trigger a message. I do not know how to implement it. that is my question

Comment: But have you _tried_ anything?  Have you done any research for checking the existence of one string inside another?

Comment: At the moment, code can only read php file for(scheck.php). i do not know how to implement the checking just still working on it. thanks

Comment: Could you get a prompt and grep in the files? (or find in all files from any good text editor if in Windows) It would be much easier...

Comment: That is a nice idea @B.Go . I never thought of that. Thanks